# chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow unauthorized_client using aws cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, google-oauth

I'm trying to authorize an endpoint using `aws cognito` as [Non-Google account authentication](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/app_identity).

I'm trying it as follows:

```
chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(         
      {'url': 'https://mydomain.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=myapplicationclientid&redirect_uri=https://myid.chromiumapp.org/&state=STATE&scope=aws.cognito.signin.user.admin', 'interactive': true},
      function(redirect_url) {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
          sampleSupport.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
          changeState(STATE_START);
        } else {
          //sampleSupport.log(chrome.identity.getRedirectURL());
          sampleSupport.log('Token acquired:'+redirect_url+
            '. See chrome://identity-internals for details.');
          changeState(STATE_AUTHTOKEN_ACQUIRED);
        }

      });
```

In the aws amazon cognito application configuration menu I set the Callback URL(s) as follows:  https://myid.chromiumapp.org/provider_cb. Also, I set the `Authorization code grant` option with the `aws.cognito.signin.user.admin` allowed OAuth Scopes.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I'm receiving the following error:

```
Token acquired:https://myid.chromiumapp.org/#error_description=unauthorized_client&state=STATE&error=invalid_request. See chrome://identity-internals for details.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In URL you request `response_type=token` while in configuration `Authorization code grant` is enabled. Either change `response_type` to `code` or enable `Implicit grant`
2. For correct redirect URL you can use `chrome.identity.getRedirectURL()` [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/identity/getRedirectURL) instead of manual construction